# error: no match for call to '(std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>})

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, iostream, ofstream

I have built this code to output a binary file containing a look up table for a multiplexed 7 segment display.

I am pretty new to coding but am learning. I think I am pretty close, but I am not sure what I am missing to make this code run properly.

I get this error for each loop:

> error: no match for call to '(std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}) (uint32_t, int8_t&)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

uint32_t value = 0;

int main()
{
    //Program data bytes

    cout << "Writing Binary File2";

    int8_t digits[] = {0X3f, 0X06, 0X5b, 0X4f, 0X66, 0X6d, 0X7d, 0X07, 0X7f, 0X6f, 0X77, 0X7c, 0X39, 0X5e, 0X79, 0X71 }; // 7-segment display output bytes for hexidecimal


    std::ofstream fout1("HexDisplay.bin", fout1.binary|fout1.out);

    if (!fout1) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening output files.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (value = 0; value <= 65535; value +=1){
        fout1(value + 0, digits[(value / 1) % 16]);
    }
    cout <<("OnesDone!..."); //

    for (value = 0; value <= 65535; value +=1){
        fout1(value + 65536, digits[(value / 16) % 16]);
    }
    cout <<("TensDone!...");

    for (value = 0; value <= 65535; value +=1){
         fout1(value + 131072, digits[(value / 256) % 16]);
    }
    cout <<("HundredsDone!...");

    for (value = 0; value <= 65535; value +=1){
        fout1(value + 196608, digits[(value / 4096) % 16]);
    }
    cout <<("ThousandsDone!...");

    fout1.write((char*)&fout1, 1);

    cout << "Programming Complete!...";
}
```

Comment: `fout1(value + 0, digits[(value / 1) % 16]);` -- can you briefly quote the snippet from your C++ textbook that led you to believe that this is the correct way to use a `std::ofstream` to accomplish what you want to do here?

Comment: the coding I know I learned from Arduino projects and many, many online tutorials, that code is mostly from an arduino eeprom programmer project, and a small bit of code I use to output another binary file. i have attempted to interpret and transpose them to this layout

Comment: _the coding I know I learned from Arduino projects and many, many online tutorials_ This is not a good way to learn the language.  Some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, as it turns out I was 90% there, I had to do a little research on  how `std::ostream` works, but all I needed was some insertion operands that I missed and adjust the `ofstream` command syntax:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

uint32_t value = 0;
uint8_t bytes[8][262144] = {0x00};

int main()
{
    //Program data bytes
    cout <<"Writing Binary File2";

    int8_t digits[] = {0X3f, 0X06, 0X5b, 0X4f, 0X66, 0X6d, 0X7d, 0X07, 0X7f, 0X6f, 0X77, 0X7c, 0X39, 0X5e, 0X79, 0X71 }; // 7-segment display output bytes for hexidecimal

    std::ofstream fout1("HexDisplay.bin");

    if (!fout1) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening output files.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (value = 0; value <= 65535; value +=1) {
        fout1 <<(value + 0, digits[(value / 1) % 16]);
    }
    cout <<("OnesDone!..."); //


    for (value = 0; value <= 65535; value +=1) {
        fout1 <<(value + 65536, digits[(value / 16) % 16]);
    }
    cout <<("TensDone!...");

    for (value = 0; value <= 65535; value +=1) {
        fout1 <<(value + 131072, digits[(value / 256) % 16]);
    }
    cout <<("HundredsDone!...");

    for (value = 0; value <= 65535; value +=1) {
        fout1 <<(value + 196608, digits[(value / 4096) % 16]);
    }
    cout <<("ThousandsDone!...");

    cout <<("Programming Complete!...");
}
```

Works Perfect!
Thanks for all your humble advice to a novice.

Comment: Your use of `operator<<` on the `std::ofstream` doesn't do what you think it does, because 1) your use of the [`comma operator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) is getting in the way, and 2) `operator<<` writes *formatted* output, not binary output. Perhaps you meant to use `ofstream::write()` instead?